# sizeof void* is unknown

Tags: configure, fftw, icc

I am compiling FFTW 3.1.2 on Mac OS X 10.7.3 with Intel's Compiler 13.1 and I get the following error at align.c:

```
ifftw.h(122): warning #147: declaration is incompatible with "void *alloca(size_t={__darwin_size_t={unsigned long}})" (declared at line 36 of "/usr/include/alloca.h")
  void *alloca(size_t);
        ^

ifftw.h(154): catastrophic error: #error directive: sizeof void* is unknown!
  #    error sizeof void* is unknown!
       ^
```

The configuration scripts sets it to be zero and the config.h file contains:

```
#define SIZEOF_VOID_P 0
```

Even if I comment it out I still get the error. The error is cast by ifftw.h and the following code:

```
#ifndef HAVE_UINTPTR_T
#  if SIZEOF_VOID_P == 0
#    error sizeof void* is unknown!
#  elif SIZEOF_UNSIGNED_INT == SIZEOF_VOID_P
     typedef unsigned int uintptr_t;
#  elif SIZEOF_UNSIGNED_LONG == SIZEOF_VOID_P
     typedef unsigned long uintptr_t;
#  elif SIZEOF_UNSIGNED_LONG_LONG == SIZEOF_VOID_P
     typedef unsigned long long uintptr_t;
#  else
#    error no unsigned integer type matches void* sizeof!
#  endif
#endif
```

So it seems that the size of pointer of void shouldn't be zero but it is in my case. This isn't the case when compiling the code on Linux. What's wrong here?

Comment: Why are you even trying to build such an old version of FFTW ? Why not just get the current version (3.3.x) from e.g. Homebrew ?

Comment: Because the old version is a part of a huge project and I've been working with for a while. If I decide to upgrade it I'll have to do an enormous amount of testing and I don't know whether it's worth it. BTW if I compile with -DHAVE_UINTPTR_T I will skip the problem but the question is what the consequences will be if any?

Comment: So if you just do `./configure CC=icc && make && sudo make install` that fails as described above ? What if you just use the Apple compiler ?

Comment: This is how I run it: `./configure --enable-shared --disable-fortran --disable-dependency-tracking CC=icc CFLAGS="-mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -m64"`. With or without the C flags it fails in the same way.

Comment: OK - what if you use gcc ? (Note that performance is much the same with gcc and icc for FFTW since there's nothing much left for the compiler to optimise).

Comment: I am not allowed to compile it with anything different from icc 13.1.

Comment: I am actually building 3.1.3 and getting this on Windows. Have you found the solution for this?